# Picklist value greater than the previous selected value

Tags: apex

I have a picklist in that I have 3 values '2015', '2016', '2017' If user selects '2016' and he adds another row now the value previously selected '2016' should not come in picklist next value '2017' should come. How could I do it using Apex.

```
public void AddMaxRow()
{
    try{
        max.add(new Maximum_Units__c());
    }catch(Exception e)
            {
                ApexPages.Message MyMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage());
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            }
}

<apex:selectList value="{!c.Name}" size="1">
     <apex:selectOption itemLabel="{!Year(today())-1}" itemValue="{!Year(today())-1}"/>
     <apex:selectOption itemLabel="{!Year(today())}" itemValue="{!Year(today())}"/>
     <apex:selectOption itemLabel="{!Year(today())+1}" itemValue="{!Year(today())+1}"/>
</apex:selectList>
 <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!AddMaxRow}" reRender="pb" immediate="true" />
```

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: @TusharSharma I am confused right now We cant create custom validations on custom settings. I have edited my code

Comment: What exactly happens when the user adds a new row? I see that is rerenders pb but pb isn't included in the code sample. It sounds like you are trying to change the available selectOptions depending on how many rows have been added, but you want to maintain the old picklist values from the old rows but prevent them from selecting them a second time in another row? Is that right?

Comment: on your controller when you initialize a new row for list keep all old selected value in set and then remove these old values from options.

Comment: @MorganMarchese yes morgan you are right

Comment: @TusharSharma how should I do it in code

Comment: @Anzar Please edit your post to clarify your question and include your controller code.